# Create video from a series of single frames and use original audio

Tags: premiere, animation

I am looking for some advice on how best to create a video which is comprised of a series of single frames from an original piece of 30fps footage.

I can create the effect by making a screen recording and using the right arrow key to advance the track. Visually this is what I want BUT the issue is with the audio. Because Quick Time Player screen recording uses my computers internal mic the original sound is compromised (i.e. it’s a n audio recording of an audio recoding) and it gets distorted.

Here is what I have currently: [View Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hytlhgg5hsr7l65/Anne%20Bean%20-%20Closer%20to%20now%20-%20FINAL.mov?dl=0)

The visual is okay but you should be able to hear the audio (even when it is much slowed down) better than you can on this version.

**Two questions:**

1. Any idea how achieve the effect I am after automatically, using Premiere or After Effects.
2. Any fixes for using the original audio - without having to re-record.

All help and ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

if it is something like "Stop-Motion Videography" that you need,
Follow 13 steps

{The keyboard shortcut are defaults of windows, for your case use that of MAC}

1. Target your 'PlayHead' to the position you want in 'Sequence' or 'Source Monitor'.
   2.When the position you selected is the one which shows the photo you want to use as single frame or photo.
2. If you are in Source monitor Skip to
3. If you are in Sequence Panel go to "Program monitor"(shift + F4)
4. Use button named "Export Frame"(CTRL+Shift+E), if not available make it visible by finding in from "+" button on Right-bottom.
5. Choose the Image_Format, Name & the Path to save.
6. Check "Import into Project".
7. A new photo will appear in the "Project Panel".
8. export as many frames as you want.
9. Set them manually or whatever the way you want & your visual is ready.
10. to set the audio Right click on the audio part of the clip and 'uncheck "Enable"'.
11. Set the audio as you like & Re 'Enable' it.
12. Set the audio & image sequence in your preference & You are good to go.

Tell me if anything get confusing or I'm Wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you want to record your system audio whilst doing a screen capture, you could use a tool like Soundflower to map the system audio as an input device.

That way you would get a direct recording into QuickTime.

Here's a blog post with details on how to do that: https://www.christianengvall.se/record-audio-soundflower/

Answer (score 1):

That's not a good way to do it.
Download a videoeditor, like Davinci Resolve (Free).
There you can import the images with 30FPS and add the audio.

Comment: Some links are helpful here, so people don't download the wrong thing, like malware or something.